# Inserting an image into a pre-developed SQLite DB for use with Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Ive developed a DB for use with my app but I've realised that I actually want extend my db to incorporate images! I will be hosting the db online but for now I am using it locally for development purposes. To create my db I have been using SQLiteBrowser, which I think is a standalone version of the Firefox SQLiteManager plugin, however I cant see a way to insert an image. I recognise that an image will have to be transfered into a byte array and stored as a blob, but rather that developing this element of the db programatically, I was wondering if the was a gui tool to help me skip this developmental element!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it makes more sense to store the image on disk and only put the file location in your DB.  Then you can skip the whole blob <-> byte array conversion and use normal file operations to load the images.

I know that didn't answer your specific question, but if you change your process to the above you might not need the original method, and may save some time and effort as a bonus.

Comment: yer nice one I'll run with your idea for now, seems like a pretty logical step! Cheers